# How can I create multiple ul-lists dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have a `<ul>` "ul-list-one", which contains a number of checkboxes. If I check the checkbox and click the move button it means that it will move to another `<ul>` "ul-list-two", and the checked checkbox will be removed from the previous, which here would be "ul-list-one".

In "ul-list-two" I can do the same, and it moves to the next, this time "ul-list-three".

Note: "ul-list-two" and "ul-li-three" will be created dynamically.

Here I have done some work, but how can I be able to create multiple `<ul>`s dynamically?

```
      $('#mer').click( function() {
        var txtBox = "";    
        var txtstatus = false;  
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').each (function() {             
        var t = $(this);
        var from = 'checklist';
        var val=$("#hidden_id").val();
        var to = 'ch';
        if (!t.is(':checked')){
            var swap = to;
            to = from;
            from = swap;
           } else { 
            txtstatus = true;
           }
       $(':checkbox:checked').attr('disabled', true);
       $('#'+to).append(t.attr('name', to).parent());
       $('#ch').addClass('br');        
       });
       if(txtstatus){
        txtBox = "<input type='text' value=''>";
        $('#ch').after(txtBox);
       }
      });  

      //close buttom code
      $('#cls').click( function() {
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').each (function() {          
        var t = $(this);
        var from = 'checklist';
        var to = 'ch';
        if (t.is(':checked')){
            var swap = to;
            to = from;
            from = swap;
           }
       $(':checkbox:checked').attr('disabled', false);
       $(':checkbox:checked').attr('checked', false);
       $('#'+from).append(t.attr('name', from).parent());
       });
      });
```

Comment: 26 views, 0 answers. I suggest you to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) so people can play around.

Comment: what will be the pattern of you list. give some `html` structure

Comment: Why do you need to create the 2nd and 3rd list dynamically? If you are always going to have exactly 3 lists, you can just create them at runtime. Then store all of your list items from the 1st ul in an array and use the .next() and .prev() jQuery methods to move them back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest thing I have ever written. If you want to leave the empty ul's, just comment out the removeEmpties call. I didn't worry about checkbox order, but it would be easy to implement in a separate function after the checkbox is moved. I also assumed you wouldn't want them to move backward beyond the initial ul. If you want that functionality, you could just add another else if to the move function.

http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/13225/